# when a person clicks their Facebook notification, they get an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my Rails App, a user can invite other users with a Facebook dialogue that appears on a button click:

[image]

In the Facebook page of a person who is invited, they get this notification message:

[image]

And when they click the notification they get:

[image]

The problem happens when they click the message **in** the notification - the 'Jennifer Collins sent you a request'. They get the page:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Sorry for all the images but best way I can think of to get the message across. The settings of my FB app look like the image below. Almost every FB problem I've had in relation to this FB invite part involve a change in these settings, so I'm hoping it's something simple here. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's the url of page where you see "The server refused the connection"

Comment: @Sahil Mittal: The url of the page is https://apps.facebook.com/populisto_com/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=1431007127114042%2C218066365038129&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request  Do I need to buy a ssl cert or something?

Comment: Yes of course, does `https://poputo.com` even exists? I mean is your domain SSL certified?

Comment: Thanks for that info. I just bought an ssl cert - cheap one for about 10 dollars, so it better work! Will keep you posted with the result..thanks.

Comment: Everything working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not have an ssl certificate. I bought one here for less than $10, and now everything works as planned.

http://www.cheapssls.com/comodo-ssl-certificates/positivessl.html?years=5